# What is the legal age of retirement in IT companies in India

Tags: employment, india

I am aware that retirement age for government employees in India is 58.
But what is the legal retirement age in **IT/Software companies in India**?

If someone wants to **work till 70** ( assume he is fit & knowledgeable to do the work), will the software company allows him to work?

Or will the software company enforce him to leave the company on his **58th birthday itself**?

Comment: I thought it had been raised to 60 for gvt employees, but  I might be wrong (as is often the case).

Comment: ^and... it might vary from state to state.

Comment: Why do you think there is a separate rule for IT companies? [This site](https://www.zeebiz.com/personal-finance/news-employees-provident-fund-organisation-will-retirement-age-be-increased-and-what-will-be-benefits-to-employees-central-epfo-commissioner-kk-jalan-explains-197530) from 2022 says *"The retirement age in India is between 58 and 65 years. While the age is 58 years for private employees, it is up to 65 years in many government departments."* You ask "will the software company enforce him to leave the company on his 58th birthday?" but I guess that depends on how badly they need him.

Comment: @WeatherVane That link really helps. I am in my mid age. knowing retirement age will help to plan my financials. Really I want to work till 65.